# Silverlight: How to make my custom control act like a button

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I have a custom control and I would like it to act like a button i.e. when you hover over it changes a little so it seems "clickable" to the user

I actually acheived this using the MouseEnter and MouseLeave events and changing the gradient but...

is there a way to apply a style to the user control and say something like TargetType="button" so that it "acts" like a button automatically?

I feel the way i'm doing it is not the best way

Answer (score 2):

As sniper says, you can set a Controltemplate for each state.

Alternatively, `you can completely replace a control's visual tree with anything you want - while still keeping the control behavior intact.`  Check out [this post by ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-7-using-control-templates-to-customize-a-control-s-look-and-feel.aspx) on the topic

Comment: This sounds like the best approach to me, depending on what your user control actually does and how complex it is. Remember that a Button is a ContentControl, so you can actually set anything as its Content not just text and then you could tweak the template as you like. If the control starts doing a lot more than a basic button then I might consider deriving from ButtonBase and creating a new default style for the control with the expected parts and states.

Answer (score 0):

In Expression Blend 3, you can edit the different states (Normal, Hover, pressed, selected etc), of any control how you need it. just select your control and click `Edit copy template`

Answer (score 0):

Add border object and sets its visibility on mousehover and leave event on the control (This will look like a flat\popup button). Additionally set the control's cursor to hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can derive your control from ButtonBase, just like Button, HyperlinkButton, Checkbox, etc.